# Why is Visual Studio showing a memory leak at a pointer location that I've deleted?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm currently creating a toy language for educational purposes and have recently checked up my code for memory leaks; however, in Visual Studio I seem to be have memory leaks at random locations in my code that do not allocate anything on the heap using 'new'. Not only this, but it says that I have lost 60 bytes at memory location that I have debug printed to be deleted.

My language is setup with an Abstract Syntax Tree that generalizes certain expressions and statements. In each one of these statements there is a destroy method that deletes all the other Ast pointers that I have and deletes any of their children. This method eliminates and deletes all the excess pointers. However, there is random memory leaks in random locations as one or two pointers that I have confirmed to be deleted have not freed their memory. I have currently tried to pick up all the pointers that I have allocated with the 'new' keyword into an array of pointers and tried to free all of them, but I just end up have more leaks than my original cleanup method.

This is the parse method currently

```cpp
void Parser::parse(VirtualMachine& vm) {
    while (curr().getType() != EOF_Token) {
        Ast* ast = parseStatement(vm, true);
        ast->parse();
        ast->destroy(); // This is the cleanup method
        vm.compile();
        std::cout << "DELETING: " << ast << std::endl;
        delete ast;
    }
    vm.clear();
}
```

The main method looks like this:

```cpp
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

try {
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ace::Parser parser(file, lines);
    parser.parse(parser.vm);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "took "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 
  t1).count()
<< "ms\n";
}
catch(std::exception&) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

An example of the destroy method looks like this (BinaryAst):

```cpp
void destroy() override {
        // Destroying other object's children if they are also a BinaryAst
    left->destroy();
    right->destroy();
        // Debug Print
    std::cout << "DELETING: " << left << std::endl;
    std::cout << "DELETING: " << right << std::endl;
        // Deleting the current ast's children
    delete left;
    delete right; // This one is deleted but still has the memory leak
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
}
```

This is the parse statement method. It implicitly will return a child of the struct.

```cpp
Ast* Parser::parseStatement(VirtualMachine& vm, bool flag) {
    if (curr().getType() == EOF_Token)
        return nullptr;
    else if (curr().getToken() == "var" || curr().getToken() == "let") 
        return parseVariableAssignment(vm);
    else if (curr().getType() == LCurlyBrace) 
        return parseBlock(vm, flag);
    else if (curr().getToken() == "print")
        return parsePrintStatement(vm);
    else if (curr().getToken() == "input")
        return parseInputStatement(vm);
    else if (curr().getType() != EOF_Token && peek(1).getToken() == "=") 
        return parseVariableReassignment(vm);
    else if (curr().getToken() == "if") 
        return parseIfStatement(vm, false);
    else if (curr().getToken() == "while")
        return parseWhileStatement(vm);
    else {
        auto expression = parseExpression(vm);
        if (expression == nullptr) {
            auto current = curr();
            Error::unexpectedToken(current, lines[curr().getLine() - 1]);
        }
        return expression;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

I have the debug flag set here to tell me of any errors. The output I get for the memory leaks are as follows:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->

// Al the other 8 bytes point to the same random location which does not provide any allocation for pointers
{2855} normal block at 0x01326FC8, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < H2     > 98 48 32 01 00 00 00 00 

// This is the block of memory that I have freed but shows as leaking
{2854} normal block at 0x01324880, 60 bytes long.
 Data: <`(*  Q2 <$*     > 60 28 2A 00 C8 51 32 01 3C 24 2A 00 05 00 00 00 

{2211} normal block at 0x01325DB0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < [1     > 80 5B 31 01 00 00 00 00 
{1747} normal block at 0x01326088, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < R2     > 90 52 32 01 00 00 00 00 
{1476} normal block at 0x01326F20, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <$R2     > 24 52 32 01 00 00 00 00 
{1167} normal block at 0x01326E78, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < H2     > 98 48 32 01 00 00 00 00 
{823} normal block at 0x013274D0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < [1     > 80 5B 31 01 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

All the other blocks seem to point at the end of a declaration of some variables in my header files, none of which are allocating using new or are pointers. It is a little misleading trying to figure out what is or isn't leaking memory.

What I had expected for the output to be would be no memory leaks. I thought the output would have at least shown no large amount of bytes being leaked other than the random leak it was showing to location where there had not been any memory allocation.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that parseStatement returns a child class of Ast and that Ast (or its base class) has no virtual destructor. Without a minimum viable example there's not much we can do. Sorry.

Comment: I've added an update to the question with the parse statement. I hope this helps as the method does implicitly return its child class. I added virtual destructors to all the AST's. This helped with some of the leaks; however, I still have some leaks on variables that I have deleted.

Comment: Glad I could help, I would suggest you try to understand what class is the one deleted in "delete right" and why "delete left" seems to be working. But, without a minimum reproducible example (i.e. one snippet we can copy/paste in a compiler) I can't be of much help. The only other thing I can think of is that you are not checking, before invoking destroy() whether left or right are null, this is UB and UB might lead to a leak (improbable). Please try to reduce your code to a couple of classes and make a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether these leaks are just false positives. In my debug print: DELETING: 01175128
DELETING: 01165AD8
DELETING: 011786E8 where as all of these are supposed to be deleted yet I get a memory leak for them. This is quite a large project so it is hard to make a sample executable.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue using std::unique_ptr, thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: @AshishBailkeri *I'm just wondering whether these leaks are just false positives. In my debug print: DELETING: 01175128 DELETING: 01165AD8 DELETING: 011786E8* -- Where are you writing the corresponding statements showing memory allocation?  A memory leak means that you allocated something by whatever means, and *did not* issue a `delete` call.  So checking `DELETING` isn't going to show anything in regards to objects you failed to delete.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand that a memory leak meant that I was not doing proper delete call. The reason I put the debug print was to see the objects I had deleted. In the print it explicitly told me the addresses that were deleted. In those addresses, one of those happened to be one of the ones that Visual Studio was telling had a memory leak which was why I was confused. The debug prints were printed just above any of my deletion statements.